# Compile python file that references to xlsx files without compiling the xslx files

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to compile my py file but end up with an error.
The scripts reads from 2 excel files and write back to 1 
When compiling the py file i get error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.xlsx'`. While the file is there and can be found when i execute the py file I cant seems to fix this.
When i chande the path from relative to full, this error pops up

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename="C:\Users\userxdx\Desktop\Excellsupport\file.xlsx")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

To compile I make use of py2exe (for windows) 
what am i missing here?

Comment: Is `file.xlsx` in the current working directory? Also, backlashes have special meaning in Python string literals. You probably meant `r"C:\Users\userxdx\Desktop\Excellsupport\file.xlsx"`

Comment: yeah the files are all in the working directory and i just changed the backslashes to the other ones and now it seems to do something but i still dont have an exe file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because a `\` is an `escape character`. For example, "\n" will create a new line in a string. To ignore `escape characters`, place an `r` at the beginning of the string like so:

```
filename=r"C:\Users\userxdx\Desktop\Excellsupport\file.xlsx"
```